# Show all the values of selected items in a Text Box and find the Average of these values

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

[Yes I tried using this operator technique, but On selecting 2 items from list box its giving me the sum of 3 or more items, Please let me know if the picture is visible to you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl4sO.png).

Label1.Text = "";
foreach (int i in ListBox2.GetSelectedIndices()) {

```
            Label1.Text += ListBox2.Items[i].Text + ",";
            TextBox2.Text += ListBox2.Items[i] + "+";
        }
```

Comment: TextBox1.Text += ListBox1.Items[i].Value + "+";

Comment: Doesn't appear to have anything to do with SQL Server. And needs more details including sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm Trying to Upload the Sample Output, But its showing me Error.

Comment: did you try the first suggestion in the comments here?

Comment: Yes, For e.g (a,b,c,d are the items in of a listbox) on Selecting Multiple Items using a cntrl button its giving me the sum like : a+a +b+b+ c+c in a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't have your data, but lets just do this with say "id", and the Hotelname.

So, say this markup

```
<div style="float:left">
<asp:Listbox ID="LBHotels" runat="server" 
    Width="200px"
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="LBHotels_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataValueField="ID"
    DataTextField="HotelName" Height="182px" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
</asp:Listbox>
</div>
<div style="float: left;margin-left:20px">
    <h3>Occurance</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOccr" runat="server" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
    <h3>Results</h3>
    <div style="text-align:right">
        Total: <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" runat="server" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox><br />
        Avg: <asp:TextBox ID="txtAvg" runat="server" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

(used div's, just float them left against each other - a nice easy way to place things around on a web form).

Ok, then this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

            SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
            LBHotels.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            LBHotels.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And I did set auto-postback for the list box.

So, this code:

```
protected void LBHotels_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string sValues = ""; // string list of values for display into text box
    int intTotal = 0;  // total value

    int[] Choices = LBHotels.GetSelectedIndices();
    for (int i = 0; i < Choices.Length;i++)
    {
        ListItem MyChoice = LBHotels.Items[Choices[i]];
        if (sValues != "")
            sValues += "+";
        sValues += MyChoice.Value;
        intTotal += Convert.ToInt32(MyChoice.Value);
    }

    txtOccr.Text = sValues;
    txtTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString();
    txtAvg.Text = "0";

    if (intTotal > 0)
        txtAvg.Text = 
           String.Format("{0:0.####}", (decimal)intTotal / Choices.Length);

}
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

:

Comment: Thankyou very very much , This is exactly what I was searching :) God Bless you with the best :)